# ISO for Android Google APIs for VirtualBox

Tags: android, emulation, google-api, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox to emulate Android app, but I need to use MapView for our app. So I need to emulate Android Google APIs (that includes map api), not just Android APIs. However I could not fine any iso files for the Google APIs.. If anyone knows where I could find it, please let me know...

Thanks in advance..

:)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Rotemmiz is a quite good way to get access for Google-Maps-API like on a Android-Google-API emulator.

You just have to copy the jar and xml file from an google api emulator onto one without api functionality. You will find the files under the following paths:

```
/system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml
/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar
```

`/system/` should be mounted as rw on the target device. Android x86 allows you to set that flag during the installation process. ([more details](http://www.callum-macdonald.com/2011/02/06/missing-com-google-android-maps/))

This can also be an Android x86 virtual machine (just use DDMS to make changes on the filesystem).
In my VM that works realy great.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - removed my wrong answer !

Google Maps is proprietary software and Google have not approved inclusion in Android-x86.
Approval is not being sought as it is not normally granted to groups who are not members of the Open Handset Alliance.

You cannot install the Shared Library on Android x86.

if you do want to try though, you can use [this](http://www.callum-macdonald.com/2011/02/06/missing-com-google-android-maps/) link, it might work, but I believe it won't be very stable on a device with different instruction set (The library was optimized for ARM devices).

What you can/need/have to do is probably use a real device. sorry for this kind of solution but that's the best the internet has to offer right now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I am using android-x86-2.2-generic.iso for the VirtualBox and my project already set the level as Google API.. However When I install my app to VirtualBox, I have "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY" on console and "Package .... requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!" on LogCat. Still have a problem... What is the problem???